# ReactJs | Login requires refresh

Tags: reactjs

My login page doesn't work and need a refresh to be logged in. input data is displayed in the console with 201 but I have to manually refresh the page to continue.

this is my login.js:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    state = {};
   submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const logingdata ={
            email : this .Email,
            password: this .Password
        }
        
           axios
           .post('/api/UserLogin', logingdata)

           .then(response => {
               console.log(response); //to print response in console in developper tool
               
               localStorage.setItem('login', response.data.token);
              console.log(this.Email);{
                  const loginmail=logingdata.email
                  console.log(loginmail);
              }
               
           })
           .catch(error => {
               console.log(error => console.log(error.response.data))
           })
    }

    
    render() {

        return (

            <div className="outer">
            <div className="inner"> 
            <form onSubmit={ this.submitHandler}>

                <h3>Log in</h3>
                
              //Login form comes here.
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" >Sign in</button>
               
                <p className="forgot-password text-right">
                    Forgot <Link to= "/Forgotpassword" >password?</Link>
                </p>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I can not figure out what the issue is. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What it should do after login. You didn't redirect?

Comment: Yes. the form stays as it is with the input data (but the network call is success) even after i click "sign in". I used history and onclick events. but it did not worked. They directs to the target route but the network call don't success.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting user data logged after post api response. but react don't see the changes on localstorage.

You need to make your components to react to local storage changes.

Use something like [react-use-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-localstorage)

then you can look if the user data changed and render the logged components, or send the user to a new route for example.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are presenting is saving the token in the localStorage and probably other components are handling the redirection when you will have that information in the storage. You will need to redirect to a specific URL ( home page probably ) after `localStorage.setItem('login', response.data.token);` and that's it.

Comment: Yes.. can you please show me how to redirect to "/" (home) ? you mean using history?

Comment: props.history.push('/')

Comment: @DevindiSiwurathna you can redirect in many ways depends on how the `Login` component is connected with the router. Try `this.props.history.push('/')`